# Why I am getting the WSO2 DSS Mapping issue?

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am trying to map my MongoDB with the `WSO2 DSS`. But the service generated is faulty and getting many errors regarding the mapping of the data.

Here is  what I tried:

```
<data name="MongoDB" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="mongodb">
      <property name="mongoDB_servers">127.0.0.1:27017</property>
      <property name="mongoDB_database">domain_with_email</property>
      <property name="mongoDB_write_concern">NONE</property>
      <property name="mongoDB_read_preference">PRIMARY</property>
   </config>
   <query id="search" useConfig="mongodb">
      <expression>domainemail.find({"domain":#})</expression>
      <result escapeNonPrintableChar="true" outputType="json" useColumnNumbers="true">{&#xd;"entries":&#xd;{&#xd;"id":"$_id",&#xd;"domain":"$domain",&#xd;"emails":[&#xd;  {&#xd;    "email":"$email"&#xd;  }&#xd;]&#xd;}&#xd;}</result>
      <param defaultValue="yahoo.com" name="domain" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="search">
      <call-query href="search">
         <with-param name="domain" query-param="domain"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

Here is the errors:

https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/b4aa22c39205d61a25f2bee5b45a7607

Kindly let me know what I need to do to get a JSON output from my MongoDB using WSO2 DSS?

Answer (score 1):

We're still struggling with our WSO2 + Mongo journey too.  Anyhow I hope this can help.  Here's our code for a working JSON service to MongoDB

```
<data name="MongoTestDS2" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="MongoDS">
      <property name="mongoDB_servers">xx.xx.xx.xx</property>
      <property name="mongoDB_database">mydb</property>
   </config>
   <query id="GetTestVals" useConfig="MongoDS">
      <expression>things.find()</expression>
      <result element="Documents" rowName="Document" useColumnNumbers="true">
         <element column="document" export="id" name="Data" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
   </query>
   <query id="InsertTestVals" returnUpdatedRowCount="true" useConfig="MongoDS">
      <expression>things.insert("{id:#, name:#}")</expression>
      <result element="UpdatedRowCount" rowName="" useColumnNumbers="true">
         <element column="1" name="Value" xsdType="integer"/>
      </result>
      <param name="id" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="name" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <query id="GetValsJson" useConfig="MongoDS">
      <expression>things.find()</expression>
      <result outputType="json">{&#xd; "Documents": {&#xd; "Document": [&#xd; {&#xd; "Data": "$document"&#xd; }&#xd; ]&#xd; }&#xd;}</result>
   </query>
   <operation name="GetThings">
      <description>Test Mongo DB                                                                 &#xd;                                    </description>
      <call-query href="GetTestVals"/>
   </operation>
   <operation name="PutThings">
      <call-query href="InsertTestVals">
         <with-param name="id" query-param="id"/>
         <with-param name="name" query-param="name"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
   <operation name="GetThingsJson">
      <call-query href="GetValsJson"/>
   </operation>
</data>
```

In your case I think, it's this line you need to change:

```
<query id="GetValsJson" useConfig="MongoDS">
      <expression>things.find()</expression>
      <result outputType="json">{&#xd; "Documents": {&#xd; "Document": [&#xd; {&#xd; "Data": "$document"&#xd; }&#xd; ]&#xd; }&#xd;}</result>
</query>
```

This returns all the fields into a string.

If this is then related to your earlier question, then I think this tutorial will help with the next step of mapping field from one service to another:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Transforming+Message+Content

On our side, we unfortunately gave up on the mongodb adapter that comes with WSO2 and used RESTHeart to expose the mongodb as APIs (http://restheart.org/)  This seems to work well as WSO2 then just consumes them as if they were any other REST API.

We'd love to hear how you get on as I'm sure we'll hit many of the same challenges in our own mongodb + WSO2 testing.

Comment: Is there no way I can display the documents in the way categorized in my question sample. Say like email with email tag and domain with domain tag, etc. Don't you think that the document will give me a complete document json, which is what I want to I want to display the output with category.